# Page rendering time are not steady in IE6

Tags: rendering, internet-explorer-6

I have to support IE6 and I calculate rendering time by creating a timestamp in javascript at the beginning of the page and doing the difference when document.ready is fired in jQuery.

If I do 3 pages load, the rendering times in milliseconds can look like this :

```
page 1 : 735, 2672, 734
page 2 : 3063, 1516, 3375
page 3 : 8281, 2531, 3703
```

Why is that? How can I have more consistency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without knowing a whole lot about the pages in question, it could be due to just about anything.  could be due to the browser caching things, etc.

Answer (score 0):

1. Exit all other programs.
2. Perform each render with the same conditions.

These conditions include an empty cache.

Answer (score 0):

Something to do with your internet connection possibly? I don't know, without more details it really could be anything.